# phpMyAdmin: Create column that increments after updating any data in its row

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have an SQL database with over 800 entries and 40 values for each entry.  I would like to add a column that increases every time any of that row's values change.  It would be like a version number for each individual row so I know which rows have edited data.

I know little to nothing about sql coding, I just use phpmyadmin to hold my data.  Is something like this possible without adding some sort of function, and if not, how would I go about implementing something like this.  Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use triggers to do this job. Run the following query in phpmyadmin after editing the table name and column name for count

```
CREATE TRIGGER incr_on_update BEFORE UPDATE ON yourtablename
FOR EACH ROW SET  NEW.count =OLD.count+1;
```